# How to check if column values exist in multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables and my first table holds 10 records, I like to check whether those 10 records exist in other tables and put a yes or no condition, all of them have a shared column which is col1, something like this

```
Table1/Col1   Table2/col1   Table3/col1  Table4/col1
1              Yes            No            Yes
2              Yes            Yes           No
3
4
5
6
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists` in a `case` expression:

```
select t1.col1,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.col1 = t1.col1) then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as in_table2,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.col1 = t1.col1) then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as in_table3,
       . . . 
from table1 t1;
```